# Windows.ApplicationModel.Package not available in NUnit-Test in .NET 4.5 (Windows 8 App)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nunit, .net-4.5

I want to create an NUnit test in an Windows 8 app (under .NET 4.5) where I read the contents of an XML file in my application to run some code on this XML structure.

In the NUnit test I want to do something like this:

```
        var file = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"testxml.xml");

        // settings
        var _Path = @"InternetZeitung\Tests\testxml.xml";
        var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        // acquire file
        var _File = _Folder.GetFileAsync(_Path).GetResults();
        Assert.IsNotNull(_File, "Acquire file");

        // read content
        var _ReadThis = Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);
```

The I would do something with this. The problem is that calling `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package` in any way raises an exception, because the unit-tested code isn't a package. Now how can I then read a file from the project using the .NET 4.5 APIs without using this (to my knowledge) only way to find out the path of the file?